# wp get_comments(); древовидные комментарии

Tags: wordpress

Стоит нестандартная задача кастомизации шаблона комментариев через функцию get_comments(); функция wp_list_comments(); не совсем подходит для меня. Вывел первый уровень вложенности вот так:

```
<?php
                                $comments = get_comments();
                                $p_comments = [];
                                foreach($comments as $comment)
                                {
                                    if($comment->comment_parent === '0')
                                    {
                                        $p_comments[] = $comment;
                                    }
                                }
                                // echo '<pre>' . print_r($comments, true) . '</pre>';
                            ?>
```

Подскажие пожалуйста как рекурсивно вывести дочерние комментарии каждого комментария?

Comment: Ответ в вопросе - рекурсивной функцией) А вообще - почему не подходит `wp_list_comments`? Не могу представить адекватную ситуацию, в которой он не подходит

Comment: Добавь параметр walker и сделай свой класс для обратки, а не город ерунду в как сейчас ты хочешь сделать)